# A good cross-browser alternative to onmousewheel event?

Tags: javascript, html

## Hello World!

---

I am looking for a **cross-browser** alternative to **onmousewheel** event.

I have a full screen canvas, and I want the user to be able to zoom in & zoom out.

**The way I do it:**

(simple example)

```js
var scale = 1000;
function wheel(e){
scale = scale - e.deltaY <= 100 ? 100 : scale - e.deltaY;
document.getElementById("coolDiv").innerText = "scale: " + scale;
}
```

```css
#coolDiv{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="coolDiv" onmousewheel="wheel(event);">scroll your mouse over me!</div>
```

**My issue:** it is not cross-browser, it works on chrome, but on some other browsers it does not.

Comment: Which other browser ?

Comment: It doesn't work for me on firefox or internet explorer for some reason

Comment: Not a solution, but `onmousewheel` was deprecated in favor of `onwheel`.  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_onwheel.asp -- although the two combined do cover the 5 listed browsers.

Comment: I guess I'll need to figure out another way to do it instead of scroll, but it's a shame. You'd think that mousewheel event would be cross-browser, turns out it isn't

Comment: The whole MouseWheelEvent itself is non-standard to begin with: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseWheelEvent so your expectations are out of place.

Comment: Is there an alternative tho? Cause I really want the user to be able to zoom